# print command instead of echo in linux

Tags: shell, command, echo

I simply can print a message in terminal using linux `echo` command.

```
prayag@prayag$ echo "prayag works on JVM"
prayag works on JVM
```

Can I have the same output with `print` command.

I actually went through their manuals, where `$ man print` describes it as Run-mailcap-programs which term I never heard before. And came to know that it is used to find the correct program to open a file with, based on MIME.

### So is there any way to **print a simple line** using `print` alone instead of `echo`?

Found similar kind of problem at [Need to assign the contents of a text file to a variable in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14116748/432903), but people suggesting `echo` over `print` there.

I tried following, but got issues.

```
$ print --"text/plain" "prayag works on JVM"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "prayag works on JVM" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "prayag works on JVM"
```

It asks for a file, with file provided.

```
$ print --"text/plain" application.properties 
Warning: unknown mime-type for "application.properties" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"
```

But got working in combination with `awk` command with a file provided,

```
$ awk '{print}' application.properties 
prayag works on JVM
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @slm I'm on ubuntu

Comment: OK, see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're confusing many things here, let me try and tease this apart for you.

1. `awk '{print}' ...`

   This has nothing to do with the `print` you're asking about. `awk` is a dynamic programming language which contains its own commands, of which `print` is one of them.
2. `print --"text/plain" "prayag works on JVM"` and other forms

   The command `print` is for displaying files per the contents of the mailcap file, using the designated "handler" for each particular file type, not for printing strings to the screen.

   *excerpt from the print man page*

   > run-mailcap, view, see, edit, compose, print - execute programs via entries in the mailcap file
   >
   > run-mailcap (or any of its aliases) will use the given action to process each mime-type/file in turn.  Each file is spec‐
   >      ified as its mime-type, its encoding (e.g. compression), and filename together, separated by colons.  If the mime-type is
   >      omitted, an attempt to determine the type is made by trying to match the file's extension with those  in  the  mime.types
   >      files.  If the encoding is omitted, it will also be determined from the file's extensions.  Currently supported encodings
   >      are gzip (.gz), bzip (.bz), bzip2 (.bz2), and compress (.Z).  A filename of "-" can be used to mean "standard input", but
   >      then a mime-type must be specified.
3. `echo`

   The command `echo` is a builtin command to the shell you're using called Bash (I'm assuming you're using Bash). You can confirm this by using this command:

   ```
   $ type -a echo
   echo is a shell builtin
   echo is /bin/echo
   ```

   You'll notice that `echo` is also a standalone executable, `/bin/echo`. This is a different command than the `echo` you're using, but serves a similar purpose.
4. `print` in shells such as zsh/ksh

   Thanks to @Gilles comment, the `print` command you're looking for is most likely the one that is built into shells such as `zsh` and/or `ksh`. You can see its usage through the man page, `man zshbuiltins`.

   #### Example

   ```
   zsh % print "hello world"
   hello world
   ```

   You can run one of these shells by typing `zsh` or `ksh`.

#### printf

Perhaps you're looking for the command `printf`?

```
$ printf "%s\n" "hello stringy world"
hello stringy world

$ printf "this is some padded digits: %04d\n" "10"
this is some padded digits: 0010
```

The command `printf` takes a formatting set of special characters so that you can instruct it how you want to display things such as strings or digits etc. See the man page for `printf`.

#### mailcap

So a lot of people are probably oblivious as to the file `/etc/mailcap`. This file contains mime-types (headers from files which identifies what type of file a file is). You can then create entries in this `mailcap` file which designate what tool to use to open a particular mime-type for a file.

#### Example

```
text/html; /usr/bin/sensible-browser '%s'; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html
application/x-troff-man; /usr/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tutf8; copiousoutput; print=/usr/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tutf8 | print text/plain:-
application/x-ogg; /usr/bin/mplayer '%s'; description="OggVorbis Audio"
application/ogg; /usr/bin/mplayer '%s'; description="OggVorbis Audio"
audio/mpeg; /usr/bin/mplayer '%s'; description="MPEG Audio Format"
audio/x-mpegurl; /usr/bin/mplayer '%s'; description="Icecast Playlists"
audio/x-ms-wax; /usr/bin/mplayer '%s'; description="Audio Format"
```

The above lines say that if you get a file with the mime-type `audio/mpeg`, then use the tool `/usr/bin/mplayer` to open this file.

These rules are generally used by the email tool, but other tools can take advantage of these entries within the `mailcap` file as well.

If you're interested in learning more about mime-types or mailcap see the following references.

#### References

- [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)
- [Mailcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailcap)

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf command to do so,

```
 # printf Hello World
 Hello

 # printf "Hello World"
 Hello World
```

Well, exatly you need to use print commnad then you can add alias

```
 # alias print='echo'

 # print Hello World
 Hello World

 # unalias print  < -- to revert.
```

also to set permanent,

```
 # export print='echo'

 # print Hello Linux
 Hello Linux
```

so,

```
# export | grep print
declare -x print="echo"

# unset print   < -- to revert.
# export | grep print
```

Answer (score -1):

- printf: more portable,  c style
- print : more  controllable  (ksh, zsh)

As for zsh, I think print is better than echo.

to show each entity in a seperate line:
`print -l $fpath` vs `echo $fpath | sed 's/ /\n/g'`